# Use user control name without namespace prefix

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Lets say I have a user control such as this:

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="WPFUserControl.MyUserControl" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtName" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btnClickMe"
            Content="Greet Me" />
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

and a Window like this:

```
<Window
    x:Class="XAMLUserControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:control="clr-namespace:WPFUserControl"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">

   <Grid>
      <control:MyUserControl/>
   </Grid>

</Window>
```

Is there a way I can refer to the user control without using the `control:` prefix?

So, instead of writing

```xml
<control:MyUserControl/>
```

I would use

```xml
<MyUserControl/>
```

Comment: Is there a reason this is not allowed? @NawedNabiZada

Comment: That's a reference to the namespace, you can create another control with exact same name in another namespace, and how should xaml know which one you are referring to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute?view=net-5.0) to make the namespace containing `MyUserControl` "belong" to the same xml namespace (something like this : http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation, basically the value assigned to `xmlns` itself in your UserControl's xaml) as all native wpf components. That should let you use your UserControl without having to use a namespace prefix.

Usage for your example would be in AssemblyInfo.cs, doing `[assembly:XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "WPFUserControl")]`.

The first paramater is the xml namespace that will be used and the second parameter is the c# namespace that contains the things you want to use without prefix in xaml.

You can find more info about how XAML and C# namespaces work together [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#mapping-clr-namespaces-to-xml-namespaces-in-an-assembly)

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But what if Microsoft some day provides a control in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" namespace with the same name? Seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @KlausGütter I never said it was a good idea, I just showed how to do what the asker asked for